# Oracle Apex get cookie from an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How can I get the value of a cookie in oracle from a request that was originated with ajax from a non-apex page (inside an apex server)?

I wanted to start by creating a function that returns the value of the login cookie and use that function to return the value to the browser to see that it can be done.

So I created a resource template and handler with the following source: `select test() from dual`.
The `test` function is declared as:

```
create or replace function test return varchar2
is
   c owa_cookie.cookie;
begin
   c := owa_cookie.get('LOGIN_USERNAME_COOKIE');
   return c.vals(1);
end;
```

When I run `select test() from dual` from an sql commands window I get the value of the cookie, but when I send a request to the handler with ajax I get the following error:

```
An error occurred when evaluating the SQL statement associated with this resource. SQL Error Code 6502, Error Message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 354
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_COOKIE", line 59
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_COOKIE", line 179
ORA-06512: at "<no need to see this>.TEST", line 5
```

I've been using the following call (checking the result through the network dev tools)
`$.ajax({url: "<handler url here>"})`

Update:
The reason I'm using a rest service is because the page that originates the request is not an apex application but it is on the same domain (so it has the same cookies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I think is happening: The cookie is sent as part of the http request header of your apex application call. The rest call is *another* http request, unrelated to your apex http request and I don’t believe the header of that request includes the cookie. So in the database session that is created as part of your rest request the cookie will not exist. You could probably set the header of the rest request yourself to fix this.

--UPDATE--
To check which cookies can be read, create a rest handler of source type pl/sql with the following source:

```
DECLARE
  l_names owa_cookie.vc_arr;
  l_vals owa_cookie.vc_arr;
  l_num_vals INTEGER;
BEGIN
    owa_cookie.get_all(
        names => l_names,
        vals => l_vals,
        num_vals => l_num_vals);
    APEX_JSON.open_array('cookies');        
    FOR r IN 1 .. l_names.COUNT LOOP
    APEX_JSON.open_object; -- {
    APEX_JSON.write('name', l_names(r));
    APEX_JSON.write('value', l_vals(r));
    APEX_JSON.close_object; -- } cookie
    END LOOP;
     APEX_JSON.close_array; -- ] cookies
END;
```

The apex username cookie is not in that list of cookies. I suggest you create your own custom cookie in an after-login process in apex.
I verified that a cookie set with the following code in an apex process is picked up by the rest handler (based on blog https://www.apex-at-work.com/2012/05/apex-simple-cookie-example.html)

```
begin
owa_util.mime_header('text/html', FALSE);
owa_cookie.send(
name => 'CUSTOM_USER_COOKIE',
value => :APP_USER,
expires => sysdate + 30 );

apex_util.redirect_url (
p_url => 'f?p=&APP_ID.:1:' || :SESSION,
p_reset_htp_buffer => false );
end;
```

Comment: The cookie definitely gets sent with the ajax request. I've already checked the cookies on both requests (network>request>cookies) and they are identical.

Comment: Could you setup a sample testcase in a dedicated workspace on apex.oracle.com ?

Comment: I don't have an apex/oracle account

Comment: That is an environment where you can request a workspace to try things out at no cost - not for production. You don't need an oracle account.

Comment: I requested a workspace and recreated the basic structure of the system. Here is the "non-apex apex application" https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/nzapptest/r/84308/files/static/v1/index.html

Comment: when I execute this it shouldn't give me a cookie value - since this is initiated from a static html file there is no apex session and no cookie. You state "from a request that was originated with ajax from an apex page" in your question. The idea of a sample testcase is that you provide credentials so I have have a look. Can you create an additional user and share the credentials ? Then describe the exact testcase (or put that as text in an app region on the test app)

Comment: I just created a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Since there is no authentication, the function is reading the only cookie available at the time (`JSESSIONID`). 

p.s. I think the cookie gets added on the first ajax request so you probably have to press F5 for reliable results.

Comment: and login credentials for the workspace ?

Comment: I'm sorry man I have no idea what you mean. When I asked for a testcase I meant for you to give me the real test case so I can investigate as a developer (with a basic app and workspace credentials so I can reproduce). Instead you just give a link to a page. I can't debug that for you I'm sorry.

Comment: Ok, can you give me your email so I can create an account for you? It won't let me create an user without an email.

Comment: just put your own email in it (it's only needed for password recovery which is not needed in this case), create a user named "guest" or so and set the password to "NOT" change on first login. Provide me user/pwd  and workspace name.

Comment: Workspace: `NZAPPTEST`
Username: `testtest`
Password: `testtest`

Comment: Ok I'm in. But please provide me an exact testcase. What exactly are you doing - what are you expecting - with details (as I asked in one of my previous updates)

Comment: The staticapp application has an `index.html` file which calls the rest call `test` `test` `GET`, which runs `select test() from dual`. If you run `select test() from dual` from SQL workshop / SQL Commands it works fine.

Comment: Did some tests. Only the jsession cookie is seen - check the restful service https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/nzapptest/test/k . I suggest you do some more research on owa_cookie to see if you can read more cookies. The GET handler I created should get you going.

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't the function work when it get's called from the rest service? Isn't the inside of the function call a pl/sql scope just like the handler you created?

Comment: I'm no longer in the app now and have no time to look into it anymore today. The  value of the cookie (in owa_cookie) is not a varchar, it is a record (check documentation). Look at my code to see how it should be parsed. I believe that was causing the error. What you probably could do to solve the original issue is set a cookie yourself in the apex app containing the value of the APP_USER and read that cookie in the restful service.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I would like to know why the collection query doesn't work but the PL/SQL works. Is there a way to get it working a collection query and a single select statement? Regardless I will accept the answer and award the bounty right before the bounty ends.

Comment: collection query should work just as well. It's just a lot easier when developing to start with pl/sql.

Comment: What is wrong with the collection query I've already written?

Comment: It's working fine but only if there is a cookie it'll error out if there is no cookie set since no exceptions are caught.

Comment: I can't get it to work, I created the function `cookie_func` that just returns the value of the `JSESSIONID` cookie, the procedure `cookie_proc` that does the same thing but instead uses an output parameter and the `cookie_proc_func` function that returns the output of the procedure. I created 2 pl/sql handlers, 1 calling the function and 1 calling the procedure and 2 collection query handlers, 1 calling the plain function and the other calling procedure wrapper function. Both pl/sql blocks work without any exception handling and both collection queries throw the same exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237415/discussion-between-koen-lostrie-and-nick-zoum).

Answer (score 1):

To get a cookie from an AJAX request within APEX, you can use the `OWA_COOKIE` package, but you do not need to define any templates or handlers. It can all be done from within the page (or calling an external procedure from within the page). Below are the steps I used to get the JSESSIONID cookie.

I have built an [example application on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-testing/ajax-test) that you can check out.

#### Page Setup

The page is very simple with just one text box and one button. The button's action is set to **Redirect to URL** and this is the target:

```
javascript: apex.server.process("AJAX_TEST", { }, { success: function (pData) { console.log(pData); apex.item("P10_JSESSIONID").setValue(pData); }, dataType: "text", error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { } }).always(function () {  });
```

The javascript is calling the AJAX Callback (which is shown below) and storing the output in the P10_JSESSIONID page item as well as logging it to the browser console.

[image: Page setup]

#### AJAX Callback Setup

The code in the AJAX Callback is very similar to the code you shared. I am getting the cookie then printing it out with HTP.P. This is all that is needed to return the value of the cookie to the page to be used for whatever you'd like. You can also make the code in the AJAX callback call a standalone procedure compiled into the database if you so choose.

[image: Ajax Callback setup]

### Update

I updated my example application so that there will be a dropdown showing all of the cookies, then you can select from the list and click the button to send an AJAX request to get the value of that cookie.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the reason I was using a rest service and not an apex action was because the request is from a page that is on the same domain as the apex server (so all the cookies are readable) but that page is not an apex application (so no apex JavaScript libraries). Sorry for not mentioning this sooner, I'll update the question.

Comment: Can this be achieved without using the apex JavaScript library?